# amqpTemplate.convertAndSend returning error message after 3 minutes

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have two machines running rabbitMQ in ha-all mode. One of those machines got into a bug condition of the version 3.3.5 that starts a "broken" non-functional queue reported in this link [bug queue limbo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/SZ7Nf09qymQ/BSdItw_4jOMJ)
With that scenario of the locked queue my application got stuck trying to send an asynchronous message.
I'm using a direct exchange with spring-amqp.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The send method is

```
amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(object);
```

The 3 minutes of hold was reported in our log

```
2016-01-13 14:54:46,680 [REFID:] [DEBUG] [] [Service] Sending message to RabbitMQ using AmqpTemplate
2016-01-13 14:57:57,637 [REFID:] [ERROR] [] [Service] Error sending message to RabbitMQ
```

So, is there any way to put a timeout to the method amqpTemplate.convertAndSend? I tried to find the timeout method in the documentation and there is only a timeout for the connectionFactory. In a method that is asynchronous why it got stuck for so long?

Comment: Not sure if we can find any `timeout` option there for you, but I'm sure it would be better to upgrade to the latest RabbitMQ as Michael Klishin suggests.

Comment: Yeah, it is already upgraded. Thanks for your comment. Do you know if is there any other way to convertAndSend with some kind of control in order to not hold the app like reported in this scenario?

Comment: Well, you can use something like `AsyncTaskExecutor.submit()` and wait some short timeout on the result `Future`.

Comment: I thought about AsyncTaskExecutor but I don't think that will be the better approach to fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such a `socket-write-timeout` option. Anywhere...

Comment: Ok Artem, thank you very much for your comments!